# Multiple youtube embeds on page getting mixed up

Tags: javascript, windows, google-chrome, youtube

I have 3 YouTube videos embedded on [this page](http://massey.vcu.edu/patient-care/teams/hematological/). One in the first tab of the main content and two on the sidebar.

On Google Chrome for windows, it seems that the video are swapping places randomly.

Any ideas why?